# Control 12v DC motor with arduino and two relays in both directions

Tags: motor, relay

I am using an Arduino and two relays to control 12V DC motor in both directions.

For the first trials it worked fine. Finally, my Arduino was fried on another direction swtich.

I think there is something wrong in the schematic.
I believe that Arduino was killed by reverse voltage spike produced by motor.

Probably I need a diode across the motor. However, I have two directions here.

So, what is the proper schematic for my task would be?

Here is my schematic.

[image: SCHEMATIC]

Comment: That is not a schematic, that is a wiring diagram. Anyway, post the code too. Most likely you control both relays simultaneously. Try controlling one relay first, then a delay until motor is stopped, and then the other relay.

Comment: please don't crosspost https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81902/control-dc-motor-in-both-directions-with-two-relays

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fluo4t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Generally it's better to use a completely separate supply for the motors and to actually use the opto-isolation that is built into your relay module rather than bypassing it by tying the grounds together.

Answer (score 1):

You want to place EMI caps across the motor wires, as close to the motor as possible.  Also, place a cap from each motor wire to the case of the motor. 0.1uF 50V ceramic should work fine.

On your Arduino to relay interface, make sure that there is a flyback diode across the coil.
[See this question here for more info on the diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150815/zener-diode-selection-for-relay)